# Computing depthmap from 3D reconstruction model

Tags: image, matlab, computer-vision, 3d-reconstruction, structure-from-motion

I'm using VisualSfM to build the 3D reconstruction of a scene. Now I want to estimate the depthmap and reproject the image. Any idea on how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the camera intrinsic matrix `K`, its position vector in the world `C`  and an orientation matrix `R` that rotates from world space to camera space,  you can iterate over all pixels `x,y` in your image and perform:

[image: Pixel ray calculation]

Then, find using ray tracing, the minimal `t` that causes the ray to intersect with your 3D model (assuming it's dense, otherwise interpolate it), so that `P` lies on your model.  The `t` value you found is then the pixel value of the depth map (perhaps normalized to some range).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My problem is that I don't have K, and R. But I think I can get an estimate of C. My goal is to align a bunch of images taken from the same scene in different times. SIFT did not work to my expectations, so I read in a paper that I can use structure from motion to align images.

Comment: Here it means when you put the images on top of each other, the geometry structure of the scene does not change.